# In php how to post a value which created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, session

In  a php page ,i created textboxes diynamically in javascript and i want to post these values to another php page how can i get these values ?  And these are my codes ;

```
while (secenek>0){

var textBoxname = document.createElement('input');
    textBoxname.name = 'textyetiskinname'+secenek;
    textBoxname.id='textyetiskinname'+secenek;
    textBoxname.type = 'text';
    textBoxname.className='selectTravelInputFieldsCarJS';
    document.getElementById("yetiskindiv").appendChild(textBoxname);

secenek--;
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to send them to a php script with ajax? Or do you just need to get the value of the input with `textBoxname.value`?

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: There is no such thing as "a PHP page". You have an HTML page. Maybe it was generated by a PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the entire snippet of script, then you need to build more script to do the ajax function.

If you are just trying to grab value of the dynamically created element, then you can use `document.getElementById('textBoxname').value;` as this code will grab the value.

Answer (score 0):

set a unique attribute on your input tags:

```
//at this to your while loop
textBoxname.setAttribute("phpform", "myform");
```

to be able to find them and then read the form data and send them like this:

```
function POST_data(callback){
    var myinputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[phpform=myform]");
    var formData = {};
    for(var i=0;i<myinputs.length;i++){
        formData[myinputs[i].getAttribute("name")] = myinputs[i].value;
    }

    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", "php_url");
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState==4){
            callback(req.response); 
        }
    };
    req.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
}
```

call `POST_data` and give a callback for your callback scenario, like this:

```
POST_data(function(response){
    //you can check here if it was successful or not and continue your scenario
});
```

just be careful, this code is using a sample ajax request, in the real world you'd better use jQuery or at least a cross-browser ajax function.